# Appengine image crop tool returns None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop images using the google.appengine.api.images.

Unfortunately trying to crop an image with size 612x612 with these parameters returns None:

```
(0.0, 0.14052287581699346, 1.0, 0.85947712418300659)
```

It does not generate an Exception or any meaningful error message; just a None return value.

Any idea?

EDIT:

the following is the entire code I am using:

```
path = urllib.unquote(path)
r = urllib.urlopen(path)
image_data = r.read()
img = Image(image_data = image_data)
width, height = float(img.width), float(img.height)
max_height = 440.0
max_width = 940.0

rest_height = 0.0
if height > max_height:
    rest_height = height - max_height

rest_width = 0.0
if width > max_width:
    rest_width = width - max_width

left_x = rest_width/(2 * width)
top_y = rest_height/(2 * height)
right_x = 1.0 - left_x 
bottom_y = 1.0 - top_y

img_cropped = img.crop(left_x,top_y,right_x,bottom_y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use execute_transforms method which will return the image after all of the image Operations are specified. Specifying crop just adds that operation to a queue of operations to be performed and does not return an image instance at that point.

So you would do 'img_cropped = img.execute_transforms()'

have a look at an example in the overview docs for the image service https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution I looked for :)